# RTesseract causing "no such file or directory" error under Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tesseract

I am trying to use RTesseract and mini_magick to do some simple OCR in a Ruby program for some images with white background color and pink font color. Unfortunately, I keep having issues with RTesseract. I have  Tesseract-OCR v3.05 installed via the .dll executable found online and stored in my `Program Files (x86)` folder. I also have ImageMagick v6.9.9 installed via its own executable in `Program Files` folder (not x86). Here is my code:

```
require "mini_magick"
require "rtesseract"

RTesseract.configure do |config|
  config.processor = "mini_magick"
end

image = MiniMagick::Image.open("input.png")
image = RTesseract.new('input.png').to_s
puts image
```

As you can see, it is a very simple piece of code. It executes without a problem when I have the RTesseract code commented out, but as soon as I call RTesseract's functionalities, things like the following began to rise up:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rtesseract-2.1.0/lib/rtesseract.rb:182:in `convert': No such file or directory - tesseract "C:/Users/NORMAL~1/AppData/Local/Temp/20170801-8600-1evxygh.tif" "C:/Users/NORMAL~1/AppData/Local/Temp/1501649603.1925441244"  -l eng         (RTesseract::ConversionError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rtesseract-2.1.0/lib/rtesseract.rb:194:in `to_s'
        from testingTesseract.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

I have tried a lot of different things, but nothing seems to get this confounded gem to work. I would've gone to a different language or wrapper by now, but this gem is central to my project and I desperately need a solution.

When I set the environment variable `PATH` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR`, `tesseract` became a recognized command and `convert -version` started to give the output `Invalid Drive Specification`. The error now seems to be that ImageMagick is not recognized/found by the calls.

Comment: I know nothing about tesseract, but do you have ImageMagick installed? If you type convert -version in a shell window, what do you get returned?

Comment: Thanks for replying! This is what I got:

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 6.9.9-4 Q8 x64 2017-07-29 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp xml zlib

Comment: Have you added the tesseract executable to your PATH?

Comment: Would that be done by going into settings and manually adding it? And also, I am not certain to which of the files I would set the path to if its necessary, but I added a variable called PATH with value C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR

Comment: Hey guys, I did what Paul Coleman suggested, I updated my question to reflect the changes. It helped in a way but fmw42's suggested command doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message, although I don't use MiniMagick. I'm running the development on a Windows system, which may have been the first issue. Although I had installed RTesseract with "GEM Install RTasseract" the necessary Tesseract-OCR was not installed. This I solved with the instructions in https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki.

After that I could start tesseract from the comandline, but still not from Ruby. However, after removing the begin-rescue-end frame I got information which file caused the error. In my case (the path may depend on the installed version of RTesseract): C:\Ruby32-x64\lib\ruby\gems\3.2.0\gems\rtesseract-3.1.3\lib\rtesseract\configuration.rb. After changing line 19 to
command: 'C:/Programme/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe',
the problem was solved. As 'C:/Programme' is a typical German Windows path you should of course verify the exact path, where you can find file Tesseract.exe.

Last but not least a final hint: you should also change the language if the scanned image does not represent an English text. E.g. my test file was German and the 'ü' was translated to 'ii', the 'ä' to '6'.